# Efficiency of generators

Tags: python, performance, generator

I am writing some software to create a complex waveform (actually a soundwave) as an array. Starting with some primitive waveforms (sine waves etc), there will be functions which combine them to create more complex waves, and yet more functions which combine those waves, etc.

It might look like:

```
f(mult(sine(), env(square(), ramp()))
```

but a lot more complex.

One way of doing this would be to make each function a generator, so that the whole function tree executes once per element with each generator yielding a single value each time.

The array could have several million elements, and the function tree could easily be 10 deep. Would generators be ridiculously inefficient for doing this?

The alternative would be for each function to create and return an entire array. This would presumably be more efficient, but has disadvantages (messier implementation, no results available until the end of the calculation, could use a lot of memory).

They always say you shouldn't try to second guess Python efficiency, but will generators take a long time in this case?

Comment: I'll be one of the "they": you shouldn't try to second guess Python efficiency. *Try* it. Time it. If your actual thing is prohibitively complex, simplify it enough to get a decent idea. And once you conclude that there's not much difference and they're both fairly slow, consider whether numpy is a good fit for your use case.

Comment: Write the code and time it. It sounds like most of your code is mathematical functions and such. So if you find out that it is to slow, it shouldn't be to difficult to change the yield returns with arrays and a return in the end

Comment: Avoid premature optimization. As long as you don't make a major blunder (e.g. using linear searches over large lists rather than dictionary lookups) if you stick to common Python idioms and Python is an appropriate tool at all, you should be okay. Especially if you are writing a tool for your own use, optimizing developer time is far more important then shaving fractions of a second from the runtime.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohnColeman in questioning whether you may not opt for something more math and engineering focused like Mathematica or Maple (Maplesoft) to tackle this problem. Either of those packages likely have better optimization to handle the task you are looking to accomplish. While both of these options are commercial, if you are in an Academic Setting, then they usually have site licenses or Academic pricing for the package to make them less prohibitively expensive.

Comment: At the moment I am just trying to avoid making a major blunder and ending up with something ridiculously slow, and it looks like it should be OK. Python isn't going to be blazingly fast at this, but it looks like I will be able to create most sounds at faster than real time, which is good enough for the time being.

Comment: @AMR Maybe things are different now then they were in 2015, but numpy is the popular open source alternative to Mathematica and Maple, and has probably overtaken both in popularity in academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, generators are a good fit for this task.

Some signals have finite time (like an envelope, or a ramp), but some other signals are infinite (like oscillators).

Using generators you should no worry about this aspect, because -like the `zip()` function- a function combining (e.g. multiplying) an oscillator with an envelope, would only consume a finite amount of items from oscillator gen, because there's at least one generator which yields a finite number of samples.

Yet, using generators is very elegant and pythonic.

Recall that a generator like this:

```
def sine(freq):
    phase = 0.0
    while True:
        yield math.sin(phase)
        phase += samplerate/freq
```

is just syntactic sugar for a class like this:

```
class sine:
    def __init__(self, freq):
        self.freq = freq
        self.phase = 0.0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        v = math.sin(self.phase)
        self.phase += samplerate/freq
        return v
        # for this infinite gen we never raise StopIteration()
```

so the performance overhead is not much than any other solution you can handcraft (like the block processing, commonly used in DSP algorithms).

Perhaps you could gain some efficiency if instead of yielding individual samples, you yield blocks of samples (for example 1024 samples at time).

Comment: I knocked up a bit of code to try 3 solutions - yield every sample, yield every n samples, and process the whole array at once. There is no doubt that yielding every sample is a bit slower (5 sec instead of 3.5 sec), but for experimenting it is ok. Simplifying the coding more than makes up for it, and I think when I start using more complex functions the % difference will diminish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generators are lazy sequences. They are perfect for use when you have sequences which may be very long, as long as you can operate piecewise (either elementwise, or on reasonably sized chunks).

This will tend to reduce your peak memory use. Just don't ruin that by then storing all elements of the sequence somewhere.